# Worklight 5.0.6.1: Issue uploading CSV for multiple language when disabling older version

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-console

We have a newer version to be published and would like to disable older version using worklight console. Since our app supports multilangual, so the message prompting user to upgrade also need to be localized.

I've uploaded the following three CSV but still receive the same error

CSV #1

```
,New version available please update from app store
en,New version available please update from app store
zh-hk,有新版本更新啦
zh-cn,请更新最新版本
zh-tw,最新版本已推出請更新您的版本
```

CSV #2

```
en,New version available please update from app store
```

CSV #3

```
"en","New version available please update from app store"
```

The CSV format of #1 and #2 should be correct according to infocenter

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Ft_defining_multi-language_admin_notifications.html

Following is the procedures to reproduce the issue.

1. login worklight console
2. Click Catalog tab
3. Disable the old version
4. Click 'Enter messages for multiple languages'. A popup is shown.
5. Click 'Upload CSV' button. A file browser is shown.
6. Pick a CSV to upload, then click 'Open' button. The following error prompted.

Syntax Error: missing ; before statement

Screen capture of the error screen is uploaded here http://postimg.org/image/ncxyjt55b/

The following is the logs from SystemOut.log captured in WebSphere App Server

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader
    at     
com.worklight.console.controllers.ApplicationsController.parseCSV(ApplicationsController.ja    va:369)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)    

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at     

sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
    at   
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
```

Comment: check your installation:
in your web server find the location of worklight-jee-library.jar , use some file-explorer or unzip utility and verify this jar contains the folder: /au/com/bytecode/opencsv/ and has the file CSVReader.class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a recently discovered defect in Worklight 5.0.6.1 and a fix is available via a Worklight 5.0.6.2 iFix.

Please have the customer open a PMR so that the iFix could be provided to you.